# How to download a category of words from Wiktionary?

Tags: mediawiki-api, wiktionary

I want to download all countable nouns ([Category:English countable nouns](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category%3aEnglish_countable_nouns)) from **Wiktionary**,
I tried some corpus on [Index of /enwiktionary/latest/](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/), but it looks hard to extract the category I want. Can anybody tell me which one I should use and how to extract the word list of a specific category? Or is there any other method to do so, like using API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers). https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:English_countable_nouns&cmprop=title gives:

```
{
"warnings": {
    "query": {
        "*": "Formatting of continuation data will be changing soon. To continue using the current formatting, use the 'rawcontinue' parameter. To begin using the new format, pass an empty string for 'continue' in the initial query."
    }
},
"query-continue": {
    "categorymembers": {
        "cmcontinue": "page|302d342d30|474610"
    }
},
"query": {
    "categorymembers": [
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "$100 hamburger"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "%ile"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "&lit"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": ".com"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "/b/tard"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "0"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "0-10-0"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "0-10-2"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "0-12-0"
        },
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "0-2-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Add `&cmlimit=max` to get the maximum of 500 members at once, instead of only 10.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Nemo's answer, here's a bash script to loop through the API. It's a little slow, but should work fine for smaller categories. It requires `jq` to be installed, and outputs the word list to standard out.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Download all words in a category from wiktionary
# Usage: ./download-wiktionary-category.sh "English_contractions" > contractions.txt

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

download() {
    local category="$1"
    local continue="${2:-}"
    resp="$(curl --silent "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:${category}&cmprop=title&cmlimit=max&cmcontinue=${continue}&format=json")"

    echo "$resp" | jq -re '.query.categorymembers[] | select (.ns == 0) | .title'

    next="$(echo "$resp" | jq -r '.continue.cmcontinue')"
    if [[ $next != null ]]; then
        download "$category" "$next"
    fi
}
download "$1"
```